# Cannot find Apple's step by step guide for setting up the provision profiles?

Tags: iphone

When I set up my provision profiles for my old computer Apple had a step by step guide on the provision portal.  I do not see it there.  There are how to's but not a step by step guide and nothing for setting up a distribution profile.

Does this document still exist? Are there any other step by step guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is do you have a distribution certificate installed on your machine? If the answer is YES move on to App ID section below

**Distribution Certificate**

1. If the answer to the above question is no, and you have no backup of your existing certificate, you will need to revoke the existing one in the iOS provisioning section at http://developer.apple.com and then click on "Request certificate"
2. Open keychain, request certificate from certificate authority, enter your name and email. Save it to disk.
3. Back to provisioning portal, click select file and choose the file you just saved. Give it a few seconds, refresh the screen and download the distribution certificate. Double click it to install it on Xcode.

At this point you should have a valid distribution certificate.

**App ID**

1. If you are creating an ad hoc distribution profile, you can create a wildcard app ID here. Enter any name you like and * for the build ID. This means you can use the same app ID for any adhocs build you create.
2. If it's for the app store, you need to name the bundle and this will need to match whatever you have setup on Xcode.

**Distribution provisioning**

1. Click provisioning then distribution, new profile. Choose if it is for App Store or Ad Hoc (see points above re: App ID), give the profile a name and in case of ad hoc ones, selected which devices you want to grant access to this distribution.
2. Once done, click submit, wait a few seconds and refresh the screen. Click download and double click to install the dist certificate on Xcode.

At this point you should have a valid distribution provisioning profila that matches your distribution certificate.

1. Go to Xcode, select your project, choose build settings and assign the distribution profile to your chosen configuration (usually release if for app store).

This was all off the top of my head so I may have missed a step or two, but hopefully you get the gist. If not feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Hi,Tank you for giving me the intructions.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you go to where you would create a provisioning profile, and there is a "How to" tab.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for giving your answer.  They have 5 how to's.  Their use to be a guid that just walked you through the proccess, without having to read diffrent how to's